# Xcode can't open my file suddenly

Tags: xcode

I've have been working on this file for a few days, but now suddenly out of the blue it won't open the file anymore.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/13085564/

Comment: Is there an error message or something?

Comment: It says something like "the program shut down unexpected" (I translated it from my native language, so Im not 100% sure how it would look in english)

Comment: Also it can open my other Xcode file/app I have.

Comment: These kinds of errors is normally fixed by removing any saved data (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode` and `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins`).

Comment: Im such a newbie when it comes to these operations. What Do I need to delete exactly? also just making sure, it won't delete any things on the app I have created so far?

Comment: @trojanfoe I'm at ~/Library/Developer/Xcode, however what should I delete here exactly?

Comment: Everything.  However you do it at your own risk.  Start with the plug-in directories.

Comment: won't it delete my whole app then? if I delete everything?
because my Xcode can open other apps, so Im not trying to fix Xcode itself.. I need to fix why it won't open this particular app I've been putting my sole into the last few days. And would cry about forever if I lost it.

Comment: I only mean deleting the directories I mention in my first comment.  This won't delete Xcode; just any settings etc.  You will have to re-download Simulators and Doc, etc. from with Xcode.

Comment: @trojanfoe So just to make sure (sorry for being such a newbie), in case my Xcode will get in more trouble, I will still have the files for my app with the code, which in theory I could transfer to another computer. ?

Comment: Yes it won't affect your project files, however they should be managed using `git` and sync'd with a remote repo (i.e. bitbucket.org).

Answer (score 0):

I found out from another topic that I had to do this and it worked!:

Open up the folder containing your .xcodeproj file. Right-click the .xcodeproj file and choose “Show Package Contents”. Then throw away everything except the project.pbxproj file.

Comment: Thankfully, you got your issue resolved. If you're just getting started with iOS, I highly recommend learning how to use `git`. This will keep you from having "scares" associated with making changes to projects and breaking them.